# How to retrieve ETag property of user photo in Azure via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Currently, calls to Microsoft Graph call to retrieve user photo metadata is missing the `ETag` property.  Is there any way to add this to the response along with the `width`, `height` information that is currently returned?  Here is a sample response.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('<user-id>')/photo/$entity",
  "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/Jpeg",
  "width": 128,
  "height": 128,
  "id": "128X128"
}
```

Notice the `ETag` is not returned with the response.

While to the contrary, the Outlook REST API V2.0 *does* return this information in its response for its equivalent API call:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/photo/$entity",
  "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('ddfcd489-628b-7d04-b48b-20075df800e5@1717622f-1d94-c0d4-9d74-f907ad6677b4')/photo",
  "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
  "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"BA09D118\"",
  "Id": "240X240",
  "Width": 240,
  "Height": 240
}
```

Can this functionality be added to Microsoft Graph so that subsequent checks for changes to user photos do not require retrieval of the entire binary image photo data but instead simply the metadata information with this vital `ETag` property?

UPDATE:
Apparently, the @odata.mediaEtag is returned with the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos` API, but I'm again mainly interested/wondering why it is NOT being returned with the Users API for a custom domain-based tenant user: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_id}/photo`.

ANOTHER UPDATE:
Based on a reply below, I did some digging, and realized that my Azure tenants do not have Exchange/Outlook/Mail enabled for any of my users (by design).  Is there different behavior for this API call when users are mail-enabled and when they are not? If so, should that not be clarified somewhere Microsoft?  Or does the API need to be updated to include the `mediaETag` for all scenarios?  Please advise.

Comment: @marc-lafleur, any way you could chime in my question please since this is sort of an urgent need for my use case.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, I'm not seeing this (using Graph Explorer). Could you try requesting full data by setting your `Accept` header to `application/json;odata.metadata=full`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, looks like my question was modified to suggest that I'm working with the Outlook API. I am not.  If you look at my first code snippet, the API I am asking specifically about is the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/ API.  I showed an example from the Outlook API as an example of what I'm hoping the desired functionlity could be.  In other words, can we carry over the same response to Users API.  Currently Users API does not return ETag info.  Thanks for your response!  Hope you can help with this request.

Comment: When I call this endpoint in Microsoft Graph Explorer, it returns @odata.mediaEtag in the response. Did you have a try with Graph Explorer?

Comment: @AllenWu, are you sure you're using the Microsoft Graph Explorer endpoint against a domain-associated tenant such as `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_id}/photos`?  When I try it in Graph Explorer the @data.mediaEtag only is returned with the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos` API.  Again, I am interested in the same result to be produced for the User api.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood your issue correctly. Because When I call it with https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_id}/photos for a custom domain-based tenant user, it returns the excepted result, which includes Etag. See screenshot here: https://screenshot.net/3jdnvaz.

Comment: Interesting...I am not seeing the same result with my Azure tenants.  I have 2 tenants still in the trial period and one subscription-enabled tenant and all 3 do not return the mediaEtag attribute.  BUT here is the difference I just discovered.  I have purposefully not enabled mailboxes or the Exchange licensing for any of my users and is it maybe that for this API call, the behavior defaults to the Outlook API (`outlook.office.com/api/v2.0`) for Exchange enabled accounts and falls back to another API without mediaEtag information for non-Exchange enabled users? I'm so confused Microsoft!

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, sir can you provide any additional feedback/assistance on this for me please?

Comment: `/me` and `/users/{id}` are the same API (`me` is just an alias for the user id). The photo is pulled from Exchange in `/v1.0`. It _will_ fall back to AAD when using `/beta` but AAD doesn't seem to support `mediaEtag` at the moment.

Comment: Thank you sir @MarcLaFleur.  I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong on my end. Any word on if this will be added at some point?